# How to change the windows pen palm rejection dead-zone ranges?

Tags: windows, touch, pen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T52W0.png)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/windows-pen-states#palm-rejection

My application needs to work in a large screen panel. The dead zone caused pen and touch cannot interact at the same time.

I want to modify this dead-zone ranges or disable the palm rejection. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you so much.